# Start VM with Script with a delay and reset the vm once?

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro

Can Someone help me make a simple script to start a vm and reset the vm after 10 seconds of delay in the background while the VM Running in Virt manager in Arch linkux (manjaro)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Would you mind explaining what scripting language should be used, and how the script is to be called (by the user, or by some automatism)?

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# The first and only arg is the name of the VM
[ -z "$1" ] && echo "Error: VM name was not provided" >/dev/stderr && exit 1
vm="$1"

virsh start "$vm"
sleep 10
virsh reboot "$vm"
```